# Styling a carousel aligned on the left (in a container) to reach the right side of the screen (out of the container)

Tags: css, vuejs2, tailwind-css, vue-flickity

I have got a flickity-carousel in a container (for centering/alignment purposes) in a Nuxt/Vue application. I would like the carousel to be aligned with the rest of my content on the left side but I would like the carousel to go until the right border of the screen. I am using Tailwind for styling.

```
<div class="container mx-auto mx-10">
  <Content_A />
  <content_B />
  <Carousel class="???"/>
</div>
```

This is what I have at the moment

[image]

This is what I want

[image]

After playing around with `overflow-x-visible` and other tailwind classes, I haven't managed to do it. If anyone knows how to do, please help me !!

Comment: Perhaps wrap containers around things individually rather than generously around all sections. Then you can use a more specific container for the carousel and utilise the advise from KingJ

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are potentially a couple of reasons why this isn't working for you.

1. The container is preventing horizontal overflow using `overflow-x: hidden`. You'll need to make sure that the container allows for horizontal overflow regardless of where the issue is coming from.
2. The Carousel is not allowing horizontal overflow due to `overflow-x: hidden` and `width: 100%`. You can either change the horizontal overflow to `overflow-x: visible` or change the width to `width: auto; min-width: 100%;`.

It's also worth checking the styles on each div in the Carousel because if there are a couple of elements between the top-level `Carousel` component and the Carousel Items themselves, the issue could be coming from one or more places within the Carousel.

Comment: I have tried all that but to no success... In the end I wrote some javascript to set the width of the carousel.